# Not able to change quantity of a commerceItem using handleSetOrderByCommerceId

Tags: java, atg

I am not able to change the quantity of `commerceItem` using `handleSetOrderByCommerceId.PFB`.

I am using Art Technology Group web commerce platform.

Here is my code snippet:

```
for (CommerceItem cI : commerceItems) {

    if (isLoggingDebug()) {
        logDebug("inside handleRemoveItemFromOrder : commerceItems iteration : "+cI.getId() +" : "+ cI.getCatalogRefId());
    }
    request.setParameter(cI.getId(), cI.getQuantity());

    if(cI.getCatalogRefId().equals(dealTobeDeleted)){
        long quantity = cI.getQuantity();
        //String currentSku = cI.getCatalogRefId();
        if(quantity > 1){

            // Set the new quantity for the commerce item being updated.
            request.setParameter(cI.getCatalogRefId(), quantity-1);
            setCheckForChangedQuantity(true);
            result = super.handleSetOrderByCommerceId(request, response);

            if (isLoggingDebug()) {
                logDebug("inside handleRemoveItemFromOrder : after super call handleSetOrderByCommerceId : "+result);
            }

        }else{
            String[] dealArray = new String[]{cI.getId()};
            repoItemIdOfCommerceItemGettingRemoved = cI.getCatalogRefId();
            setRemovalCommerceIds(dealArray);
            if (isLoggingDebug()) {
                logDebug("inside handleRemoveItemFromOrder : before super call handleRemoveItemFromOrder : "+repoItemIdOfCommerceItemGettingRemoved +" : "+getRemovalCommerceIds().length);
            }
            break;
        }                                               
    }
}
```

The logs says :

```
**** debug  Fri Sep 18 15:49:55 CAT 2015    1442584195886   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-37/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler    no form errors - staying on same page.
**** debug  Fri Sep 18 15:49:55 CAT 2015    1442584195886   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-37/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler    no form errors - staying on same page.
**** info   Fri Sep 18 15:49:55 CAT 2015    1442584195889   /com/cellc/online/commerce/pricing/calculators/OrderMonthlyCostCalculator   monthlyPrice::::::::::::::509.0
**** debug  Fri Sep 18 15:49:55 CAT 2015    1442584195889   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-37/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler    runProcess skipped because chain ID is null
**** debug  Fri Sep 18 15:49:55 CAT 2015    1442584195889   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-37/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler    no form errors - staying on same page.
**** debug  Fri Sep 18 15:49:55 CAT 2015    1442584195889   /atg/commerce/order/OrderManager    Order: o8950004  Version in object: 183  Version in repItem: 183
**** debug  Fri Sep 18 15:49:56 CAT 2015    1442584196206   /atg/dynamo/servlet/pipeline/RequestScopeManager/RequestScope-37/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler    no form errors - staying on same page.
```